# restdb.io wont let me access with GET verb although I got CORS enabled

Tags: angularjs, rest, http, cors

I have CORS enabled in [restdb.io](https://restdb.io). I have set up so all origins are allowed to make GET requests. I have generated a Api key .This is the error message and api call. The wierd thing is that if I click the request in the network tab in chrome dev mode I can see it got 200 ok from the server.  Am I missing something?

```
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

I am using Angular JS.

```
    function getImages() {


    var def = $q.defer();
    $http({
        async: true,
        crossDomain: true,
        url: getImagesURL,
        method: "GET",
        headers: {

            "content-type": "application/json",
            "x-apikey": APIKEY,
            "cache-control": "no-cache"
        }


    }).then(function successCallback(response) {

        def.resolve(response.data);

    }, function errorCallback(response) {

        console.log("Error " + response.data)

    });
    return def.promise;

}
```

Comment: try without async and crossDomain

Comment: still the same error message

Answer (score 0):

Solved it. I was using the wrong api key.